# Displaying ACF image field

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to display a list of all my custom taxonomy terms with an image field that I have created in ACF. The ACF image field I have is `<img src="<?php the_field('brochure_logo'); ?>">`, but how can I display that image in my code below? I have left a gap where the field needs to go, but I can't seem to output the image URL.

```
$taxonomy = 'brochure_categories';
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
?>
<ul class="downloadGrid">
<?php
foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ) {
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="' . esc_attr( get_term_link( $tax_term, $taxonomy ) ) . 
        '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . 
        '" ' . '>';

    echo  '<img src="    " >';
    echo  $tax_term->name;
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the term object as the second parameter to the_field/get_field.

```
echo '<img src="' . get_field( 'brochure_logo', $tax_term ) . '">';
```

Answer (score 1):

In the settings from that field you can select to output the image URL. If it returns a object, use:

```
$img = get_field( 'brochure_logo' );
```

And to output the URL, use:

```
echo $img[0]['url']
```